# Onclick events inside php code to change an image outside of the code

Tags: php, html

Prior to switching our site to PHP/MySQL, we had a click event that would change an image when a different button was selected so users could click in between different items and see the differences.  I had it set up as an image id originally.

```
<img id="Demo" src="<?php echo $default; ?>">
```

This still worked until I added a visibility toggle on the buttons (as we have some items with more options than others.

My php code for each button looks similar to this:

```
<div class="tooltip">
    <span class="tooltiptext"><?php echo $Color3; ?></span>
    <?php
        if($Hex3==NULL) {
            echo '<button class ="button button3" style="display:none"></button>';
        } else {
            echo'<button type="button" class="button button3" onClick='document.getElementByID("Demo").src = echo $image3;'></button>'; 
    ?>
```

Comment: What other image are you trying to change it to besides $image3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong quotes in your onClick attribute and breaking out of the quoted PHP string.

Is that the only problem? You do not really describe the issue.

```
echo'<button type="button" class="button button3" onClick='document.getElementByID("Demo").src = echo $image3;'></button>';
```

should be...

```
echo "<button type='button' class='button button3' onClick='document.getElementById(\"Demo\").src = \"{$image3}\"'></button>";
```

Comment: I switched it out for your code, but the issue is that the buttons are unresponsive.  When clicked, they should change to the image assigned to each $image variable.  They are not doing this.  I have an image on the left which is in my original post under the <img id="Demo> tag.  This image should change with each button.  It does not.

Comment: Is the value of the attribute not changing? Run document.getElementById('Demo') and make sure it returns the expected element.

Also, JS is case sensetive, so it needs to be getElementById, not getElementByID

Comment: The value is changing.  The image is not.  I made the change on the getElementById, but still not changing the image.

Comment: Is this page publicly accessible so I can look at the whole thing?

Comment: I only have the code for the image change on the first two buttons so far, btw.

Comment: I see:
<button type="button" class="button button2" onclick="document.getElementById(\" demo\').src="http://twinrayjstudios.com/Shop/ShopImages/Apparel/Mens/ClassicTees/Michonne/RoyalBlue.png" '=""></button>

You are not using the code I provided. It looks like you tried to use part of it and didn't change the quotes properly

Comment: I copied your "should be" code directly into my code.  Was that not right?

Comment: The image doesn't have the id of Demo. It'll work after that last change.

Comment: Ah, I forgot I had taken that out while testing a different option.  Thank you so much!  It is working properly now.

Comment: @TwinRayjStudios - The Query.php file you've linked to is using an image that's 650x650, yet is only displayed at 400x400 - is that intentional, or an oversight? It's not responsive to window size, so seems like a waste of bandwidth. Furthermore, since you've used a png where a jpg would be appropriate the waste is even larger. Saved as a 400x400 jpg, the file-size shrinks from ~ 262kb to around 26.8kb!!! Much faster to load and cheaper to host. :wink:

Answer (score 0):

Here seems to be a problem

```
echo "<button type='button' class='button button3' onClick=\" document.getElementById('Demo').src = '{$image}'\"></button>";
```

Or

```
echo "<button type='button' class='button button3' onClick=\" document.getElementById('Demo').setAttribute('src', '{$image}') \"></button>";
```